# Generating UML diagram from Scala sources

Tags: scala, uml, diagram, class-diagram

Is there any stand-alone tools (not Eclipse or Idea plugins) for generating class diagram from Scala source files?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try [Acceleo](http://eclipse.org/acceleo/) see an example of using it with scala [here](http://stephanebegaudeau.tumblr.com/post/7499662266/scala-generation-with-acceleo-3-1)

Comment: It is an eclipse plugin but I am searching for stand-alone tool (I want to write an sbt plugin).

Comment: Talk to the maintainers of Acceleo and see if you can re-use Acceleo core (the bit with the Eclipse glue stripped off) with sbt. No need re-inventing the wheel :)

Comment: Is Acceleo actually capable of generating a diagram from Scala source code? As far as I know, and as it is demonstrated in the example above, it can output a source code based on a given model, but not the other way round (that was the point of the question).

Answer (score 23):

I had exactly this problem and couldn't find anything that would quickly draw a hierarchy from some Scala source code so I ended up creating something to do it. I've put it on GitHub in case it's useful to anyone else:

https://github.com/mikeyhu/scaladiagrams

Comment: It fails to compile because of unresolved dependencies:
com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-plugin;4.0.0: not found, 
com.github.mpeltonen#sbt-idea;1.6.0: not found, 
com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.14.0: not found

Comment: For people still looking, found this project that creates proper UML diagrams for Scala projects : https://github.com/tizuck/scala-uml

Comment: The tizuck project has been abandoned.