# Scala Project Visualisation

Tags: scala, project

In Java I often liked to look at UML class diagrams to get an overview of a project.

My bachelor thesis now deals with the implementation of a project in Scala and I want to present an overview of the project-hierarchy. What are appropriate means to such? Are there any tools? As far as I have heard UML seems not to be suited for scala.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems a duplicate of [Generating UML diagram from Scala sources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227952/generating-uml-diagram-from-scala-sources)

Comment: Well, I think my question is more general. That answer didn't help me that much. I'm asking for the way you would approach such a problem.